# How to ensure that Publish message through Pubnub IOS SDK was delivered?

Tags: ios, pubnub

I am attempting to integrate PubNub iOS SDK in my project. How can I confirm that the published message was delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Message Delivered Notification

If the `publish` callback status is `success`, then you know PubNub Network received it and sent it to all active subscribers.

If you want to be notified when a subscriber or each individual subscriber (if there are more than one) have received the message, then the subscriber(s) need to send (publish) a message back to the publisher.

But how many subscribers are receiving the message? Do you want to receive a message delivered notification for all subscribers? Just something to consider.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Craig Conover, As many subscriber join, there is no limit of subscriber. I just want to confirm that all subscriber recieve publish message.

Comment: The publisher and subscribers are decoupled by design. If you want your publisher to know that a subscriber(s) have received a message that was sent, then your subscriber code needs to publish a message back to the publisher that represents the acknowledgement of received message.